# Python2.7 How do I check if a response is json (and parse it if it is)?

Tags: json, python-2.7, unicode, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I have a 'requests.models.Response' object which I would like to parse. Calling response.json() on the response makes a 'unicode' object.

Primarily - How do I check whether the response is json?

Secondarily - Can I parse a json 'unicode' object with bs4?

My code is as follows:

```
import requests

post_hdrs = { 
    'type': 'regulated',
    'url': 'node/17'
}

r = requests.post(
    url='https://www.gfsc.gg/fetch-records-for-companies-table',
    data=post_hdrs,
)

json_data = r.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content type is in the headers:

```
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'application/json'
```

After getting the json data, parse it with BeautifulSoup.  Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

post_hdrs = { 
    'type': 'regulated',
    'url': 'node/17'
}

r = requests.post(
    url='https://www.gfsc.gg/fetch-records-for-companies-table',
    data=post_hdrs,
)

print r.headers['Content-Type']
print
data = r.json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for c in soup.findAll('td',attrs={'class':'Company Name'}):
    print c.text
```

Output:

```
application/json

2Mi Financial Services Limited
71FS Insurance Company Limited
7L Capital Partners Emerging Europe L.P.
7L Equity Partners (EE) Limited
   :    :    :
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Astrophe It is odd that it's a json response that returns HTML. There's a layer of indirection that shouldn't be needed, but that is the server's issue.  Thanks for providing a working example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the response returns HTML. I had the impression that a json response would be keys and values in a dictionary - which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a valid json object, the method will throw an exception (ValueError if memory serves), which you can catch. It's Python's "ask for forgiveness" way of working.

As for handling unicode, this should do the trick:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not familiar with ast. I am getting good output with no errors but I'm not sure how to parse it - I don't want to use regular expressions and then find out I could have passed it to e.g. bs4. Is ast useful to parse unicode?

Comment: You mean r.json() returns you unicode or a proper json? If what you get in 'r.text' is unicode that holds json object, then the code I posted will make it into a proper json.

Comment: Once I've got 'proper json' using the code you've posted, can I then get a bs4 document out of it?

Comment: What's "bs4 document"? With bs4 you pull data out of HTML and XML files. In this case you already have something with semi-structure (dictionary).

Comment: json is a collection of name - value pairs, which can be translated into a dictionary. Therefore if unicode string will have json structure, then you can expect dictionary on the output. Here's an example from my code: https://github.com/tracek/gee_asset_manager/blob/master/geebam/batch_uploader.py#L147

Comment: It looks to me as though the output from r.json() is better than ast.literal_eval(r.text). What is the benefit of using your code?

Comment: If you get as a response unicode string with json structure, then with the code I posted you can turn it into a dictionary. That's an answer to your second question.

Comment: The problem I have is that I am not familiar with parsing json. I have an output which is not a series of tags or links or tables etc but instead it is just a single continuous unicode. So I don't see how it is a json object (a dictionary) nor do I see how to look at it tag by tag or link by link etc. If I use the code in your answer I get an object of type 'str'. Are you saying that this is a dictionary and that it is somehow useful for parsing?

Comment: How do I turn the object into a dictionary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127643/discussion-between-lukasz-tracewski-and-astrophe).